# Django Form Wizard: why done() method is not called after submitting?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm using a `SessionWizardView` and I can't understand why the `done()`method is never called. Instead, after posting my form, in the last step, I can see a `POST HTTP 200` on my server, but this does nothing.
The `get_form()` method works as expected.

I suspect a distraction error since I have the exact same logic for another view, and this works well.

Here is the whole code bellow.

### The view

```
class DiscountsCreateView(PermissionRequiredCanHandleProducts,
                      ModelInContextMixin,
                      RestaurantMixin, SubSectionDiscounts,
                      SessionWizardView):
    """ Wizard view to create a discount in 2 steps """

    model = Discount  # used for model context
    form_list = [DiscountForm0, DiscountForm1]
    template_name = "discounts/discount_add.html"

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super().get_form(step, data, files)

        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current

        # step0 - name, kind, tax_rate
        # => nothing special to do, always the same form

        # step1 - specific fields related to the chosen kind
        if step == '1':
            step0_data = self.storage.get_step_data('0')
            kind = step0_data['0-kind']
            # combo => combo, combo_unit_price
            if kind == Discount.COMBO:
                form.fields['combo'].queryset = Combo.objects.restaurant(self.restaurant)
                # NOTE : this is not a scalable way to show/hide fields (exponential)
                form.fields['rebate_amount'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            elif kind == Discount.REBATE:
                form.fields['combo'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
                form.fields['combo_unit_price'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

        return form

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        try:
            Discount.objects.create(
                name=data[0]['name'],
                kind=data[0]['kind'],
                tax_rate=data[0]['tax_rate'],
                rebate_amount=data[1]['rebate_amount'],
                combo=data[1]['combo'],
                combo_unit_price=data[1]['combo_unit_price']
            )
        except Exception as e:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, MSG_DISCOUNT_ADD_KO.format(e))
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, MSG_DISCOUNT_ADD_OK)

        return redirect(reverse('bo:discount-list'))
```

### The forms

```
class DiscountForm0(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        label=verbose_display(Discount, 'name'))
    kind = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=verbose_display(Discount, 'kind'),
        choices=Discount.KIND_CHOICES)
    tax_rate = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=verbose_display(Discount, 'tax_rate'),
        queryset=TaxRate.objects.all())


class DiscountForm1(forms.Form):
    """
    Contains all the specific fields for all discount kinds.
    The goal is to only show the fields related to the right discount kind
    """

    # For REBATE kind only
    rebate_amount = forms.DecimalField(
        label=verbose_display(Discount, 'rebate_amount'),
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(0)])

    # For COMBO kind only
    combo = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=verbose_display(Discount, 'combo'),
        queryset=Combo.objects.none()) 
    combo_unit_price = forms.DecimalField(
        label=verbose_display(Discount, 'combo_unit_price'),
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

### The templates

#### add_discount.html

```
{% extends "base_dashboard.html" %}
{% load verbose_name %}

{% block dashboard_title %}
    Créer une {% model_name model %} : étape {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} / {{ wizard.steps.count }}
{% endblock dashboard_title %}

{% block dashboard_content %}

    <form action='' method='post' novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'includes/_wizard_form_horizontal.html' with wizard=wizard %}
    </form>

{% endblock dashboard_content %}
```

#### _wizard_form_horizontal.html

```
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {% include 'includes/_form_horizontal.html' with form=form %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'includes/_form_horizontal.html' with form=wizard.form %}
{% endif %}


{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit"
            value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">
        &laquo; étape précédente
    </button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="étape suivante &raquo;"/>
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your final `form` isn't valid because if it were valid, there's no way the `done()` method wouldn't be called. I don't see the `clean()` method of your `DiscountForm1` but as it stands now, both `rebate_amount` and `combo_unit_price` are required

Comment: That's definitely this! Thanks a lot. Since it was a field error and that field was hidden, nothing was displayed on screen!

Comment: @Marcell Erasmus The only missing thing, is that I can't handle validation directly in form field, nor in form `clean() method`, because I need data from the previous step (ie. which kind a discount has been selected). So, I handled validation in `done()` method but I think it's not the right place to do it, since Django considers your form is valid as soon as it enters this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `done()` method is always called if the `form` submitted in the last step `is_valid()`. So if it's not, it must mean your `form` isn't valid.

In your case, you're hiding fields that are required by your `DiscountForm1`. So you're also hiding the error for these fields. You should make them optional and check in the form's `clean()` method if the appropriate fields are filled.